# C# - Change row color when I select a cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView and I want to change the color of the selected row when I click on the cell.
I did this with the below code but my problem is when I select the second row then the first row didn't change back to the default style.

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the last colored cell and restore it's coloring when another is activated.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow lastColoredRow = null;
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(lastColoredRow!=null) {
        // Restore the coloring as needed
        lastColoredRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        lastColoredRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    lastColoredRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method you would have to write a loop to update all cells to the default color, then update your current cell to the desired color.